# Performance implications of using a flatter schema

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I'm using FlatBuffers (C++) to store metadata information about a file. This includes EXIF, IPTC, GPS and various other metadata values.

In my current schema, I have a fairly *normalized* definition whereby each of the groups listed above has its own table. The root table just includes properties for each sub-table.

Basic Example:

```
table GPSProperties {
  latitude:double;
  longitude:double;
}

table ContactProperties {
  name:string;
  email:string;
}

table EXIFProperties {
  camera:string;
  lens:string;
  gps:GPSProperties;
}

table IPTCProperties {
  city:string;
  country:string;
  contact:ContactProperties;
}

table Registry {
 exifProperties:EXIFProperties;
 iptcProperties:IPTCProperties;
}

root_type Registry;
```

This works, but the nesting restrictions when building a buffer are starting to make the code pretty messy. As well, breaking up the properties into separate tables is only for clarity in the schema.

I'm considering just "flattening" the entire schema into a single table but I was wondering if there are any performance or memory implications of doing that. This single table *could* have a few hundred fields, though most would be empty.

Proposal:

```
table Registry {
  exif_camera:string;
  exif_lens:string;
  exif_gps_latitude:double;
  exif_gps_longitude:double;
  iptc_city:string;
  iptc_country:string;
  iptc_contact_name:string;
  iptc_contact_email:string;
}

root_type Registry;
```

Since properties that are either not set or set to their default value don't take up any memory, I'm inclined to believe that a flattened schema might not be a problem. But I'm not certain.

*(Note that performance is my primary concern, followed closely by memory usage. The normalized schema is performing excellently, but I think a flattened schema would really help me clean up my codebase.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most of your data is strings, the size and speed of both of these designs will be very similar, so you should probably choose based on what works better for you from a software engineering perspective.

That said, the flat version will likely be slightly more efficient in size (less vtables) and certainly will be faster to access (though again, that is marginal given that it is mostly string data).

The only way in which the flat version could be less efficient is if you were to store a lot of them in one buffer, where which fields are set varies wildly between each table. Then the non-flat version may generate more vtable sharing.

In the non-flat version, tables like `GPSProperties` could be a `struct` if the fields are unlikely to ever change, which would be more efficient.

Comment: As commented above, each buffer is stored separately from any other buffer as it represents the metadata for a single file. I've used image metadata above, but there could also be fields for PDF, Audio, Video, Filesystem, XMP, etc., metadata. Definitely over 100, but no more than "a couple hundred". Most would be empty since they are file-type dependant. (i.e.: An image fie would populate the EXIF and IPCT related fields but leave all the others at their default.) The buffer would have just the one table as its root and that data would be stored in a SQLite column.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get the 100+ fields. There's a cost of 2 bytes per unused field if it is not shared with other objects. The non-flat version could save on that only if there happen to be overlaps with other tables in terms of used/unused structure.
If your data is super sparse, have you considered a vector of unions instead?
And to be honest, if the above is still to inefficient for super sparse data, Protocol Buffers deals better with super sparse things.

Comment: Oh, wow... I missed that little detail and my testing didn't pick up on it because I was always checking the size of the buffer after setting one more parameter in the constructor. Setting the 1st and 100th fields produces a much larger buffer. I think this line in the Tutorial: _"...It also means that you do not need to be worried of adding a lot of fields that are only used in a small number of instances, as it will not bloat the buffer if unused."_ should maybe be clarified a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Basics you should be first clear with:

1. Every table has a vtable at top of it which tells the offset at whihc each field of table could be found. If there are too many fields in a table, this vtable will grow huge, no matter if you store the data or not.
2. If you try to create a hierarchy of tables, there are extra vtables you are creating and also adding indirection cost to the design.
3. Also vtables are shared if there is similar data being stored in multiple objects.. Like if you are creating objects with only exif_camera variable being used!

So it depends if your data is going to be huge and heterogeneous use the more organized hierarchy. But if your data is going to be homogeneous  prefer a flattened table.

Comment: Each buffer I'm creating represents a single file, and each buffer is stored independently in a database entry so I don't think there's any "sharing" going on. In my proposed "flat schema", there's only ever one "Registry" object in the final buffer, so I don't think I'd benefit from any v-table sharing. I've done a few quick tests whereby I create a table with 300 fields of type `int` and randomly set a small number of them. In such a basic test, things seem "ok". (i.e.: Memory usage is about what I would expect, but maybe 300 doesn't quality as "many fields".)

Answer (score 0):

> This single table could have a few hundred fields, though most would
>   be empty.

The performance cost is likely to be so small you won't notice, but your above quote, to me, is the swaying factor about which design to use.

While others are talking about the cost of vtables; I wouldn't worry about that at all.  There's a single vtable per class, prepared once per run and will not be expensive. 
 Having 100's of strings that are empty and unused however is going to be very expensive (memory usage wise) and a drain on every object you create; in addition reading your fields will become much more complex since you can no longer assume that all the data for the class as you read it is there.

If most / all the fields were always there, then I can see the attraction of making a single class; but they're not.

Comment: The FlatBuffer is not being unarchived into a corresponding C++ class. Instead, the FlatBuffer is just being used for storage. When I need the value of a metadata property, the FlatBuffer is read from the database (SQLite) and the value I need is read directly into a very basic structure that holds at most a single string, integer, double or boolean value. This is done with an _oversized_ switch statement that can map internal enum values (property tags) to the corresponding field/getter in the FlatBuffer.